# how to add a reference to the system.data.SQLite.dll to the windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm new to windows phone 7, please help me with this query.
I want to add a SQLite database in windows phone 7. I downloaded the system.data.SQLite.dll
from sourceforge(www.sqlite.org).  i add it as a reference in windows phone 7 visual studio 2010 express for windows phone. But, it  show a error message that, System.Data.SQLite.dll is not built using windows 
phone runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you downloaded a wrong .dll. ( for c# .net, and not silverlight).

If you want, you have a great tutorial for using [SQLite in your WP7 apps](http://www.wirebear.com/blog/2010/11/12/using-sqlite-in-your-wp7-app/), explains how to use SQL (tutorial uses [sqliteClient](http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com/) )