# how to add reference to system.data.sqlite.dll in wp7

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to add a reference to the system.data.SQLite.dll to the windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687806/how-to-add-a-reference-to-the-system-data-sqlite-dll-to-the-windows-phone-7)

I'm new to windows phone 7. Please help me with my queries.
I want to use SQLite db in wp7 using visual studio express 2010 for wp7.
I downloaded System.Data.SQLite.dll from www.sqlite.org... I add it as a 
reference, but it show a error that System.Data.SQLite.dll is not built using windows phone runtime.

Thank You..

Comment: Please don't re-post the same question. Please edit the original question in the future and provide more details to inspire more/better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, just as it states, it is not built for the Windows Phone runtime. The Windows Phone development stack is quite different compared to the full-blown .NET Framework.

So you have a couple of choices here:

- [SQLLite port for Windows Phone](http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com/)
- [SQL CE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)
- [Sterling](http://sterling.codeplex.com/)

Pretty sure there are more, but these are the most important ones.